# How to execute a class with main method which is present in fatJar created by gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

This is a follow up question for [how to execute a built fat JAR as a gradle task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180264/how-to-execute-a-built-fat-jar-as-a-gradle-task) 
I don't have enough points to ask my question as a comment. So I have to ask again. This question has been asked in other formats and scenarios multiple times but none of those responses helped me.

My problem:

scenario 1 : create a single jar with dependencies using gradle fatJar

scenario 2 : create a single jar with dependencies using maven assembly

Execute

```
java -cp sample.jar com.example.ClassA
```

on jar files generated in both processes.

Issue: 
jar from Process 1 gives me

**Error : Could not find or load main class com.example.ClassA**

jar from Process 2 executes correctly.

I have extracted both jar files and both of them have the same folder structure and same files - meaning the compiled class files are present in both jar files.

I haven't specified any manifest entries in either process because I have multiple main classes and I am not trying to generate an executable jar file.

My build.gradle file looks like below:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

sourceSets {
    main{
      java{
         srcDirs 'src/main/java'
          }
      }
}

processResources {
    from 'src/main/resources'
}

task compile (type: JavaCompile) {
    source = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    include '**/*.java'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
}

compile.options.compilerArgs = ["-sourcepath", "$projectDir/src/main/java"]

dependencies {
    .
    .
    .

}

task fatJar(type:Jar) {
    baseName = 'xxxxxxx'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'compile', 'fatJar'
```

EDIT - 1:

I have tried relative path to the jar, absolute path to the jar and even browsing to the folder which contains the jar. No luck whatsoever.

I have tried using '/' instead of '.' in the package name. No luck there either.

I have tried using java VM arguments providing huge enough heap space. Nada.

Tried executing on powershell. Got the below error:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Could not lo...ClassA:String) [], RemoteException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I wanted to see the contents directly so used jar -tvf path_to_jar\sample.jar . Interestingly jar command didn't execute and complained that command was not found on the classpath. I had to browse to the java installation directory and execute the command and it showed the file contents.

I am running out of ideas and options here.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, no matter which config I use for fatJar, the final jar gives errors when trying to execute the main class.

Using ShadowJar task I was able to build the necessary jar and execute the main class as specified in the question.

I know this defeats the entire purpose of the question about using fatJar and executing the main class. But due to time-constraints, I had to look for alternatives.

For those who are looking for config for Shadow Jar tasks, I did it using below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {  
        mavenLocal()    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

and finally to execute the task, I used

```
gradle shadowJar
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your execution command is not valid. After building your project with:

```
./gradlew clean fatJar
```

you should use following command to execute your program:

```
java -cp build/libs/xxxxxxx.jar com.example.ClassA
```

Parameter `-cp build/libs/xxxxxxx.jar` sets the classpath for JVM that is about to start and it has to point to the existing JAR file (you can use relative or absolute path to this file).

Take a look at following screencast I've recorded a few minutes ago:

[image]

You can see that if I change execution command to:

```
java -cp xxxxxxx.jar com.example.ClassA
```

I got exactly the same error as yours:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.ClassA
```

Here you can find a [simple Gradle project](https://github.com/wololock/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/45471440) I used to play around with your `build.gradle` file example. I've added a single dependency to prove that `fatJar` builds a JAR with dependencies and I've added to classes with `public static void main(String[] args)` to prove that you can pick any main class from command line. I hope it helps.

Comment: @2194470 I see couple of differences between what you did and my scenario. 
1. I was testing on Windows and you probably did it on Mac. I don't think this has anything to do with the issue.
2. I was executing fatJar using simple "gradle" command and you used "graddew" wrapper command. I will try this and let you know. BTW, is there any difference between using gradle and gradlew while executing fatJar?

Comment: I am almost sure that your problem is caused by the wrong path to a JAR file you pass in `java -cp ...` command. Try passing absolute path to this file in the first place. Windows/Linux differences shouldn't be a problem here since this error is thrown by JVM. Using `gradlew` has no difference comparing to locally installed `gradle` - I use it mostly because it's easier to share with others same version of gradle.

Comment: Edited the question with additional comments, can you check it once again?